# Limit concurrent sessions for a machine

Tags: ssh

I was wondering how to limit the maximum number of concurrent ssh sessions on a given machine.

Neither does `MaxSessions` nor `MaxStartups` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` seem to do what I am looking for.

Currently working on a `poky` embedded distro with `systemd` and `pam.d`

Comment: You might want to add which specific distro you use.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `/etc/security/limits.conf` for setting a maximum number of sessions per user.

If you want to allow only one session for user `eagleone`:

`eagleone   hard    maxlogins   1`

If you want to allow only one session for group `exgroup`:

`@exgroup   hard    maxlogins   1`

If you want to set the limit for all users:

`*          hard    maxlogins   1`

You might need to edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and add the following line:

`session    required   pam_limits.so`

If you exceed the login limit:

```
Too many logins for 'eagleone'.
Last login: Tue Feb 18 17:12:09 2020 from 192.168.225.37
Connection to 192.168.225.52 closed.
```

Comment: Seems not to working in my embedded distro, although what you wrote is coherent and seems the correct solution. Any way to debug this? I manage to enter with two ssh connections even setting the hard overall (*) limit to 1

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Indeed. Maybe pam.d overwrites this setting?

Comment: `#Also note that configuration files in /etc/security/limits.d directory,
#which are read in alphabetical order, override the settings in this
#file in case the domain is the same or more specific.` Have you checked them?

Comment: Yes, such directory is empty. Is there any logging or status that I could check?

Comment: See my recent edit

Comment: Tried adding the pam_limits lien to /etc/pam.d/sshd with no avail

Comment: Well, I am out of ideas. I will leave this answer here for others with different distros searching for advice.